# Why can't I pass certain expressions to a closure parameter marked @convetion(block)?

Tags: swift, closures

I discovered this weird behaviour:

Consider the following code:

```
func foo(_ x: () -> Void) {

}

class Bar {
    func bar() {
        print("hello")
    }
}

var bar: Bar? = Bar()
```

These compiles:

```
foo(bar?.bar ?? {})
```

but this does not:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: bar?.bar ?? {})
```

It produces the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type '@convention(block) () -> Void'

Now if I change `bar` to:

```
func bar() -> (() -> Void)? {
    return { print("hello") }
}
```

and then do:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: bar() ?? {})
```

It compiles!

So it's definitely not because of the `??` operator

**Question:** Can you explain this behaviour?

Everything below this point is my experimentation.

---

I spotted that the only difference between the `async` method and `foo` is that the `execute` parameter is marked with `@convention(block)`.

**Hypothesis:** I cannot pass optional chaining expressions into parameters marked with `@convention(block)`.

But this seems to be wrong, as I can do this and it still doesn't compile:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: Bar().bar ?? {})
```

It also seems like I can cast the expression to a `() -> Void` and it magically compiles:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: (bar?.bar ?? {}) as () -> Void)
```

Isn't `bar?.bar ?? {}` already of type `() -> Void`? This makes no sense!

Another way to make it compile is to extract `bar?.bar` as a local variable:

```
let barFunc = bar?.bar
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: barFunc ?? {})
```

which makes even less sense...

Comment: Not an answer but it could guide you to something might be useful: I worked with a big team that uses "SwiftLint", for some reason when I was aiming to declare something as `() -> ()`, SwiftLint forced me to type it as `() -> Void`! I was wondering what's the reason of this? should it be the same?! we already know that `Void` is a typealias of `()`... After doing a pretty quick investigation, I figured it out that `() -> Void` better to be used for matching the return conventions in the Objective-C world. It could be mean that there *is* somehow a different :)

Comment: In addition, if you check [closures doc](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html), we will notice that -maybe for some reason- they *only* use the `() -> Void` but not `() -> ()`...

Comment: @AhmadF I suspected it was something to do with `() -> ()` not converting to `() -> Void` as well, but `async(execute: (bar?.bar ?? {}) as () -> ())` magically compiles...

Comment: Also, a funny thing to mention is: although `DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: bar?.bar ?? {})` produces the error, declaring the closure in a constant and pass would make it work: `let closure = bar?.bar ?? {}
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: closure)` At this point, do you think that it should be reported a bug or something? or is there something we miss?

Comment: @AhmadF Let’s wait for a while and see if others know what’s going on.

Comment: I think you can only wait until someone fixes the (obvious) bug in the swift compiler. Or just use the work-around with the explicit variable or cast.

Comment: Yeah this looks like a bug to me – briefly looking into it, the constraint solver is encountering an ambiguity of whether to bind `??`'s generic placeholder to `@convention(block) () -> Void` or `() -> Void`. It only happens when the generation of type variables is just right though. Here are a couple more weird ones: https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/ec837cf26edce3f6f32ecd3f9fc88dc7. I'll file some bugs when I get a moment.

Comment: Filed a couple of bugs: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9839 & https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9840